# wordpress redirect for Multisite not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, wpmu

Aim : moving a multisite WordPress installation to localhost

Environment: LAMPP on Ubuntu 10.4.

I am moving a mutlisite wordpress installation to localhost. Steps that I have completed:

recreated db using the backup sql file.
copied all folders and files from the server and kept under htdocs.
now using the newly generated wp-config.php, When I tried to install a mutlisite, I was asked to add the following to wp-config.php

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/wordpress');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I have also added the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

While I access my site with the url `http://localhost/wordpress`, I am taken to `http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/` and get error message stating `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete`.

Please help me set it up correctly.

PS: I am new to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/wordpress');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');`
```

must be:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is I have not kept all files in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` the files are in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/`. And I want to use he subdirectory `wordpress` for my base. Anyways, Since I didn't get any help from wordpress forums, I will try your solution. Thanks Again.